# How to get all text before second CRLF

Tags: t-sql

I have a 3000 character field that contains multiple CRLF. I used the REPLACE function to verify that they are being stored by our import but I do not know how I can parse all the text before the second set of CRLFs?  I would assume the SUBSTRING function is used but I dont know how to isolate the second set of CRLFs.

Comment: Could you provide example data?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7ca0/1/0
Essentially I want to grab everything before TEXT3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AllTextBeforeSecondCrLf = substring(DATA1, 1, charindex(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), DATA1, charindex(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), DATA1, 1) + 1   ))
    FROM TEST
```